# How do I hide "Control.Image Property" from Property Window in Visual VB or visual C++

Tags: vb.net

I made a class derived from Button Class. It has two new properties: ImageNormal and ImageOver. I really want to **hide the default Image** property in Debug time.

Excuse me for my English, I know, I should improve it.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Show your code and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

```
<System.ComponentModel.Browsable(False)>
Public Shadows Property Image As Image
    Get
        Return MyBase.Image
    End Get
    Set(value As Image)
        MyBase.Image = value
    End Set
End Property
```